# Jmeter 3.0 confusing csv columns, when trying to generate dashboard from file, recorded with another settings

Tags: csv, jmeter, report

Here is the situation - jmeter results were recorded in .csv quite a long time ago (around 6 month). The version of jmeter was not changed (3.0) but the config files did. Now I've been trying to generate a report from the old csv as usual - using

```
jmeter.bat -g my.csv -o reportFolder
```

Also, to defeat the incompatibility of configurations, I created a file named local-saveservice.properties, and passed it through -q command line option. Playing with settings in this file, I managed to defeat several errors like "column number mismatch" or "No column xxx found in sample metadata", but I still didn't generate the report succesfully, and here is the trouble:

> File 'D:\ .....\load_NSI_stepping3_2017-03-24-new.csv' does not contain the field names h
>   eader, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be
>   read incorrectly
>   An error occurred: Error while processing samples:Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer f
>   ailed with message :Consumer failed with message :Error in sample at line:1 converting field:Latency at column:11 to:lon
>   g, fieldValue:'UTF-8'

However,in  my .csv column number 11 has the header "Latency" and contains numeric values, though 'UTF-8' is the content of next column - "Encoding"
Here are first lines of my .csv

```
    timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,Encoding,SampleCount,ErrorCount,Connect,threadName
    1490364040950,665,searchItemsInCatalogRequest,200,OK,true,25457,1,1,http://*.*.*.*:9080/em/.....Service,654,UTF-8,1,0,9,NSI - search item in catalog
    1490364041620,507,searchItemsInCatalogRequest,200,OK,true,25318,1,1,http://*.*.*.*:9080/em/.....Service,499,UTF-8,1,0,0,NSI - search item in catalog
    1490364042134,495,searchItemsInCatalogRequest,200,OK,true,24266,2,2,http://*.*.*.*:9080/em/.....Service,487,UTF-8,1,0,0,NSI - search item in catalog
    1490364043595,563,searchItemsInCatalogRequest,200,OK,true,24266,2,2,http://*.*.*.*:9080/em/.....Service,556,UTF-8,1,0,6,NSI - search item in catalog
```

PS I had to add threadName manually, 'cos it was not saved during initial data recording (my knowledge of Jmeter was even less then now :) )

Answer (score 0):

First you should update to JMeter 3.3 as there are bugs fixed in report generation in the 3 versions after 3.0.

Second add to your command line:

> jmeter.bat -p <path to jmeter.properties> -q <path to your custom.properties used when you generated file> -g my.csv -o reportFolder

Ensure that in "**your custom.properties**" you set to false all fields that are prefixed by **jmeter.save.saveservice** that didn't yet exist at the time you generated the file.